# Integrating re-captcha in angular2 / angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, recaptcha

**Background**

I am trying to integrate re-captcha in a single page application made with angular 4. I set the sitekey with `grecaptcha.render(elt, {sitekey : 'XXX-my-public-key'});`.

**Problem**

When I call `grecaptcha.render()`, I cannot be sure that the recaptcha js is loaded. Hence, sometimes, I get this error :

> LoginComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined

**Question**

How can I be sure that re-captcha is fully loaded before calling `grecaptcha.render()`?

Here are the relevant pieces of code :

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

**login.component.html**

```
<div #captchaDiv class="m-t"></div>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.less']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('captchaDiv')
  captchaDiv: ElementRef;

  [...]

  ngOnInit(): void {
    grecaptcha.render(this.captchaDiv.nativeElement, {sitekey : 'XXX-my-public-key'});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, however I think it is still relevant to future readers...

I think what you're missing is the `async` and `defer` keywords in the script tag, as indicated in the guide below.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

That said, below is my full implementation, in case the tag needs to be dynamically added and customized to a particular language (as was my need). I've followed the [guide on google dev portal](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#auto_render) on how to `explicitly render` the google recaptcha.

```
@Component({
   template: `<div #recaptcha ></div>`
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   // Get a reference to the element which will hold the recaptcha widget
   @ViewChild('recaptcha') recaptchaContainer:ElementRef;
   // Retrieve this from your config
   captchaKey:string = 'XXX-my-public-key';

   constructor(private renderer:Renderer2) {}

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.initRecaptcha('en');
   }

   initRecaptcha(lang:string) {
      // Check if recaptcha global variables are set, and if so, clear them.
      // This is required in case you need to reload the recaptcha in a different language.
      if (typeof grecaptcha !== 'undefined' && typeof recaptcha !== 'undefined' && typeof  ___grecaptcha_cfg !== 'undefined') {
          grecaptcha = recaptcha = ___grecaptcha_cfg = undefined;
      }

      // Clear the content of the element, and add div to be consumed by the script
      this.recaptchaContainer.nativeElement.innerHTML = `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="${this.captchaKey}"></div>`;

      // Append the script to load
      let script = this.renderer.createElement(this.recaptchaContainer.nativeElement, 'script');
      this.renderer.setElementAttribute(script, 'innerHTML', '');
      this.renderer.setElementAttribute(script, 'src', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=' + lang);
      this.renderer.setElementAttribute(script, 'async', 'true');
      this.renderer.setElementAttribute(script, 'defer', 'true');
   }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try to use this RecaptchaModule , https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<re-captcha (resolved)="resolved($event)" siteKey="YOUR_SITE_KEY"></re-captcha>`,
}) export class MyApp {
    resolved(captchaResponse: string) {

    }
}
```